# How to resolve Dynamic Public IP adress issue to host website on my personal server

Tags: tomcat, web-hosting

Recently i purchased domain from GoDaddy , Now i want to host small website on my own server(tomcat 6 for java application).

I have done Port forwarding on Router by making my **private** IP address **static**.

But my **Public** ip address dynamically changing. Please help me in doing a proper setting so that i don't need to always change my Public IP address in GoDaddy domain account setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dynamic DNS Service (like No-IP) to get a domain resolving to your dynamic IP, which gets updated by your router/modem or any other client in your network.

You can then configure a CNAME for the domain you want to use. A CNAME allows you to link another domain which has the correct IP. ("A linked A-record")